# Cant change phone account on contacts android 2.3.6

Tags: applications, contacts

I have 2 email accounts, one on gmail a another one on hotmail. For the android i only use the gmail account for the obvious reasons of having the services centered. But I cant change the phone account and i do not recall entering this account on the phone (but i may have entered). This is samsung ace plus, android 2.3.6 rooted. To access the menu on the screenshot go to (Contacts -> Options -> Display Options):

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

Does anyone know how I can change the phone account email?

Answer (score -1):

I Just deleted all accounts, like facebook and dropbox. Added again and resync. Worked